# spring-framework htmlunitwebdriver testing doesn't support ajax post?

Tags: ajax, spring, testing, webdriver, htmlunit

I think the spring-framework `webdriver(MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver)` testing doesn't support POST parameter passing(or encoding) correctly.

```
$.ajax(... method: 'POST', { data : {'param1' : 'param1Val', 'param2' : 'param2Val' } ...)
```

then server expect the param values but the results are null. (even the content-type header is not set correctly. Always `*/*` not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)

How can I workaround this?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isnt with your endpoint? Does the endpoint behave as expected if you hit from postman for example?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, I'm using MockMvcHtmlUnitDriver that is HtmlUnit not any real browser.

setup like this :
driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder
  .webAppContextSetup(context)
  .build();